# Mapping struct to mysql table, and binding row to struct

Tags: go

This is my first script using go-sql-driver.

My mysql table (PRODUCT) looks like:

```
id int
name varchar(255)
IsMatch tinyint(1)
created datetime
```

I want to simply load a row from a table, and bind it to a struct.

I have this so far:

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

type Product struct {
    Id    int64
  Name  string
  IsMatch ??????????
  Created ?????
}

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("hello, world!\n")

    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:@/product_development")
    defer db.Close()

    err = db.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error()) // proper error handling instead of panic in your app
    }

    rows, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM products where id=1")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error()) // proper error handling instead of panic in your app
    }

}
```

Now I need to:

```
1. What datatype in Go do I use for tinyint and datetime?
2. How to I map the rows to a Product struct?
```

Answer (score 6):

**What datatype in Go do I use for tinyint and datetime?**

For a hint as to the types that the [database/sql](http://godoc.org/database/sql) package will be using, have a look at the documentation for [database/sql.Scanner](http://godoc.org/database/sql#Scanner), which lists the Go types used within database/sql itself:

```
int64
float64
bool
[]byte
string
time.Time
nil - for NULL values
```

This would lead you to try `int64` for `IsMatch` and `time.Time` for `Created`.  I believe in reality you can use pretty much any sized `int` (maybe even `bool`, you'd have to check the source) for `IsMatch` because it can be stored "without loss of precision."  The documentation for [go-mysql-driver](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql#timetime-support) explains that you will need to add `parseTime=true` to your DSN in order for it to parse into a time.Time automatically or use [NullTime](http://godoc.org/github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql#NullTime).

**How to I map the rows to a Product struct?**

It should be something pretty strightforward, using [Rows.Scan](http://godoc.org/database/sql#Rows.Scan), like:

```
var products []*Product
for rows.Next() {
    p := new(Product)
    if err := rows.Scan(&p.ID, &p.Name, &p.IsMatch, &p.Created); err != nil { ... }
    products = append(products, p)
}
if err := rows.Err() { ... }
```

This scans the columns into the fields of a struct and accumulates them into a slice.  (Don't forget to Close the rows!)

Comment: Thanks it worked but time.Time didn't work I get this error `Scan error on column index 8: unsupported driver -> Scan pair: []uint8 -> *time.Time`  If I use string it works, but obviously I don't want string.

Comment: Looks like rows.Scan magically allows for underscores like:  IsMatch can be is_match in the db.

Comment: @Blankman If you're using the code I included for rows.Scan, then it's not using the names of the fields at all, it's using the order you specify the arguments.  See my edit for time.Time.

Answer (score -1):

**How to I map the rows to a Product struct?**
You can use `reflect` to bind `table rows in db` to a `struct`, and 
 automatically match values without long `Hard-Code` sql string which is easy to make mistakes.
this is a light demo: [`sqlmapper`](https://github.com/arthas29/sqlmapper)